# Modularize Slide Out Container ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uikit

In following the wonderful [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift), I successfully created a Slide Out Container view in my app.

I would like to incorporate this `ContainerViewController` in another place in my app, and so would like to modularize this as to not copy and paste code into another `ViewController`, however I am at a loss as to how to go about doing this.

Here is the code from the tutorial:

```
import UIKit
enum SlideOutState {
    case LeftPanelClosed
    case LeftPanelExpanded
}

class StudentContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    var centerViewController: SearchClassesTableViewController! // <--- Need to change this
    var currentState: SlideOutState = .LeftPanelClosed
    var leftViewController: StudentSettingsTableViewController? // <--- And this bad boy
    let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
        centerViewController.delegate = self

        centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
        view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
        addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

        centerNavigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
}

private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main ) }

    class func leftViewController() -> StudentSettingsTableViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StudentSettingsTableViewController") as? StudentSettingsTableViewController
    }

    class func centerViewController() -> SearchClassesTableViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchClassesTableViewController") as? SearchClassesTableViewController
    }
}

extension StudentContainerViewController: CenterViewControllerDelegate {
    func toggleLeftPanel(){
        let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)
        if notAlreadyExpanded {
            addLeftPanelViewController()
        }
        animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)
    }

    func addLeftPanelViewController(){
        if leftViewController == nil {
            leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
            addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: leftViewController!)
        }
    }

    func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: StudentSettingsTableViewController) {
        view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, at: 0)
        addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
        sidePanelController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: Bool){
        if shouldExpand {
            currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: centerNavigationController.view.frame.width - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
        } else {
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) {finished in
                self.currentState = .LeftPanelClosed
                self.leftViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.leftViewController = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    func showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow: Bool) {
        if shouldShowShadow {
            centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        } else {
            centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Gesture Recognizer

extension StudentContainerViewController {
    func handlePanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        let gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight = recognizer.velocity(in: view).x > 0

        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            if currentState == .LeftPanelClosed {
                if gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight {
                    addLeftPanelViewController()
                }
                showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow: true)
            }
        case .changed:
            if gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight || currentState == .LeftPanelExpanded {
                recognizer.view!.center.x = recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translation(in: view).x
                recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
            }
        case .ended:
            if leftViewController != nil {
                let hasMovedMoreThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x > view.bounds.size.width
                animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedMoreThanHalfway)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to swap out the `center` and `leftViewController` properties. I made a superclass, and then set the `center` and `leftViewControllers` in the subclasses' `viewDidLoad`s (see below), however this did not work and the app broke in the extension of `UIStoryboard`, in the `mainStoryBoard` class func (also shown below)

Superclass:

```
class SlideOutContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    var centerViewController: UIViewController?
    var currentState: SlideOutState = .LeftPanelClosed
    var leftViewController: UIViewController?
    let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60


...same code as above...
}
```

and subclass:

```
class StudentSlideOutContainerViewController: SlideOutContainerViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centerViewController = SearchClassesTableViewController()
    leftViewController = StudentSettingsTableViewController()

        centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController() as! SearchClassesTableViewController
//        centerViewController.delegate = self

    centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController!)
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

[image: img1]

And the line breaking with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

[image: img2]

I know it's a lot, and a long shot for any chances of solving but StackOverflow often has magical ways....

Comment: By some reason your coding is calling recursively `centerViewController` method that is what is causing your crash, can you post your class where you´re implementing this storyboard method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your implementation of your Storyboard protocol, you are calling recursively both methods `leftViewController` and `centerViewController` asking for name to instantiate in storyboard but is calling the `centerViewController` again and there is the recursive loop

I think you need define those properties as class properties, or a method in your protocol returning a static string value, to avoid the recursive call

Hope this helps you

Comment: Ahhh yes, always helps to have a second pair of eyes, thank you.

Comment: I am Glad to help you! @DaneJordan happy coding and best regards

Answer (score 0):

In mainStoryboard, instead of returning a UIStoryboard named "Main", can you try overriding the mainStoryboard method in your subclass so you return `self.storyboard` from your subclass ViewController?